# POST variable to another class

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

I have a search function using XPath, when results are shown a check box is also echoed.

```
<form name="save" method="POST" action="saveProcess.php">
            <?php
            foreach ($holidays as $holiday) 
            {
                $resultTable .=  "<p><a href=\"{$holiday->link}\">{$holiday->title}</a>" . "<br/>" . 
                "{$holiday->pubDate}" . "<br>" . 
                "{$holiday->description}" . "<input type='checkbox' name='chk' value='{$holiday->title}' />" . "<br /></p>";            
            }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

I would like this check box to hold the value of `{$holiday->title}` which when the form is submitted will be shown in saveProcess.php, i use the `isset` method to check if the variable is set and it is not.

```
if (isset($_POST['chk'])) {
    echo $_POST['chk'];
}
else
{
    echo"variable is not set";
}
```

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: Replace `<input type='checkbox' name='chk'` with `<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]'` and try again.  Also, do a `print_r($_POST['chk'])` in place of `$_POST['chk']`

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok to me, just remember that the value of a checkbox is posted only if the checkbox is checked, if it's not checket `$_POST['chk']` is not set

EDIT - since you are revriting your checkboxes as suggested in the comment use an array

```
        <?php
        foreach ($holidays as $holiday) 
        {
            $resultTable .=  "<p><a href=\"{$holiday->link}\">{$holiday->title}</a>" . "<br/>" . 
            "{$holiday->pubDate}" . "<br>" . 
            "{$holiday->description}" . "<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='{$holiday->title}' />" . "<br /></p>";            
        }
        ?>
```

And then server side `$_POST['chk']` will be ann array

Comment: It isn't okay. He rewrites his checkboxes

Comment: This solution still results in my variable not being set.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you name each checkbox "chk", and when you submit the form, the values get overwritten. That's why it doesn't get anything in saveProcess.php. What you need to do, is either specify that the $_POST["chk"] can contain an array of value, like so:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' value='{$holiday->title}' />
```

Notice the square brackets in the name. Now $_POST["chk"] will be an array.

Another way, would be to leave the html as it is, and just get the data, in saveProcess.php, using:

```
$HTTP_POST_VARS["chk"]
```

The first part basically explains why it doesn't work and how to fix it, while the second suggestion, is merely an alternate way of getting the data.

Have a great day!

Comment: This also does not appear to work, my variable is still not set